# Views and Field Collection: Merge duplicates

Tags: views, entities

I have a content type "Person" which has a field collection field "Skills". Each skill has a name and 2 other fields. Each Person can have multiple skills. I want to view each Person, with their Skill names diplayed separated with commas like this:

```
John Doe: Architecture, Light Technology
Jane Doe: Biology, Energy, Computer Science
```

Currently, I have a relationship to the field collection that enables me to display the fields used in "Skills". The problem is, if a Person has multiple Skills, one row is displayed for each Skill, so some Persons are displayed multiple times:

```
John Doe: Architecture
John Doe: Light Technology
Jane Doe: Biology
Jane Doe: Energy
Jane Doe: Computer Science
```

How would I go about "merging" these fields?